# __add__ method to disallow duplicate items

Tags: python, function, methods, built-in

I have created a new class under UserList called UList that overrides the `__add__` method - it does not allow duplicate items to be added to a list. But when I try to run it, I don't get the expected results:

```
from collections import UserList

class UList(UserList):
  def append(self,ap_item):
    for ap in ap_item:
        if ap in self:
          raise ValueError(repr(ap) + " already exists in list")
        else:
          return UserList.append(self, ap_item)
  def __add__(self,ad_item):
    for ad in ad_item:
        if ad in self:
          raise ValueError(repr(ad) + " already exists in list")
        else:
          return UserList.__add__(self,ad_item)
  def extend(self, ex_item):
    for ex in ex_item:
        if ex in self:
          raise ValueError(repr(i) + " already exists in list")
        else:
          return UserList.extend(self,ex_item)
```

How can I get this method to execute correctly?

Comment: What _do_ you see? What did you expect?

Comment: Your code works for me. What problem do *you* see?

Comment: add just overrides the `+` operator `x__add__(y)` is equivelent to `x+y`

Comment: You forgot to `return` the result.

Comment: I expected the items in y to be added to z, unless of the items already exists in z. when i run this it prints None. By the way, I am just learning.

Comment: When you run it it raises an exception: `ValueError: 5 already exists in list`.

Comment: Also, there is a logical error - you are adding the ad_item list once for each item, in your add_fucntion. The code in the  `else` clause should be outside the `for` loop.

Comment: yes but when i change the values in y to something other than what is in z it returns none. I will look at the logic error

Comment: 1. `append()` is supposed to add single items, not whole lists. So the `for` loop in them is not needed.

Comment: 2. You forgot to override `__iadd__`; this will be called when doing `a += [4]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `__add__` function lacks a `return` statement. Any function so lacking implicitly returns `None`. That explains why your function returns None.

Try this:

```
return UserList.__add__(self,ad_item)
```

Comment: thank you. in the same class i am also overrriding the extend and append methods in the same way, i'll edit my code above to show it, why do those methods work without using a return statement?

Comment: I added in return statements after the extend and append methods, but when I tested on extend, I still got None.

Comment: `None` is the correct return value from `.extend()` and `.append()`.  Try this, for example, `print ([1].append([2]))`. Those functions modify their object in place.